# Getting "Enter a valid json" when entering Headers for HTTP with Azure AD in Microsoft Flow/Power Automate

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, power-automate

I'm working on setting up a flow that will make an API request against a protected API. Since it requires authentication, I'm using HTTP with Azure AD. I'm able to sign in correctly, and I appear to be getting an authorization code:

[image]

I'd like to exchange this code for an access token so I am invoking this HTTP request:

[image]

It's complaining about the Headers not being a valid json. I'm also not sure what to include in the Body to exchange the authorization code for an access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know much about this connector, so I'm sorry that I can't explain to you why your API calls still require logging in(which you asked in previous post). But if just for the questions and screenshot you provided above, I can provide some suggestions for your reference.

In you power-automate, you can add a "Initialize variable" action to initialize a variable named "header" and set the value shown as below screenshot:
[image]

Then you can use "Parse JSON" action to parse this variable(convert it to json format)
[image]

Now you can use the "Body" from the "Parse JSON" as the value of the "Headers" box in your "Invoke an HTTP request". It will solve the issue of headers not being a valid json.

For the value of "Body of the request", you can put the value as I provided in the previous post:

```
grant_type=password&client_id=xxxxx&scope=xxxxx&username=xxxxx&password=xxxxxclient_secret=xxxxx
```

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~